# Is it possible to see who created or last modified a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I noticed a new Lightning App and Component in my org today.  Just a simple test component with just one attribute in it.  It's certainly nothing I wrote, and I asked a couple folks with admin rights if they were playing around with Lightning and wrote it, but they didn't.

Is there any way to see something similar to an Apex Class's Created By and Last Modified By info, except for a Lightning Component?

I looked in the Developer Console, but didn't see any such information for Lightning Components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

**Setup** > **Develop** > **Lightning Components**

Click on the Lightning App or Component. You will see **Created By** and **Modified By** there.

Comment: There is a change to identify the details now.  You can follow the below steps.

Setup > Custom Code > Lightning Components.

Under Lightning Components, click on Lighting Components option. Then click on any lightning component to see the Created By and Modified By details.