# Getting LastModifiedDate of a Component File?

Tags: metadata-api, rest, salesforcedx-cli

There is a post from 2019 [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152663/is-it-possible-to-see-who-created-or-last-modified-a-lightning-component/152665) that details obtaining a couple of fields about a Lightning Web Component.

Is there a way to get that information programmatically? Could not tell if trying various combinations of LightningComponentBundle in th dev console would even work since every variation returned a  `sObject type 'myVariation' is not supported`.

Also tried similar queries via the dx cli using `sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM LightningComponentBundle"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Last Modified Date of a component *bundle*, but not the individual files therein.

## Command

```
sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m LightningComponentBundle
```

## Example Output (redacted)

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": [
    {
      "createdById": "005...",
      "createdByName": "Brian Fear",
      "createdDate": "2019-07-16T13:17:55.000Z",
      "fileName": "lwc/...",
      "fullName": "...",
      "id": "0Rb...",
      "lastModifiedById": "005...",
      "lastModifiedByName": "Brian Fear",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2019-07-16T13:17:55.000Z",
      "manageableState": "unmanaged",
      "namespacePrefix": "",
      "type": "LightningComponentBundle"
    },
    {
      "createdById": "005...",
      "createdByName": "Brian Fear",
      "createdDate": "2019-03-27T16:18:13.000Z",
      "fileName": "lwc/...",
      "fullName": "...",
      "id": "0Rb...",
      "lastModifiedById": "005...",
      "lastModifiedByName": "Brian Fear",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2019-07-09T00:24:07.000Z",
      "manageableState": "unmanaged",
      "namespacePrefix": "",
      "type": "LightningComponentBundle"
    },
    {
      "createdById": "005",
      "createdByName": "Brian Fear",
      "createdDate": "2019-04-10T02:26:33.000Z",
      "fileName": "lwc/...",
      "fullName": "...",
      "id": "0Rb...",
      "lastModifiedById": "005...",
      "lastModifiedByName": "Brian Fear",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2019-07-09T00:24:07.000Z",
      "manageableState": "unmanaged",
      "namespacePrefix": "",
      "type": "LightningComponentBundle"
    },
    {
      "createdById": "005",
      "createdByName": "Brian Fear",
      "createdDate": "2019-08-20T23:03:31.000Z",
      "fileName": "lwc/...",
      "fullName": "...",
      "id": "0Rb...",
      "lastModifiedById": "005...",
      "lastModifiedByName": "Brian Fear",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2019-08-20T23:03:31.000Z",
      "manageableState": "unmanaged",
      "namespacePrefix": "",
      "type": "LightningComponentBundle"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that all times are in GMT.

To keep track of created/last-modified times of individual *files*, consider using a VCS (Version Control System), such as Git. You'll be able to track specific changes to files efficiently this way.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox that was exactly what I needed to know!